# OmniOS (Illumos) sendmail verbose option not working

Tags: sendmail, illumos, omnios

When using `mailx -v` or `/usr/lib/sendmail -v` to send mail, we are not getting any text back. Mail does go out and log entries are found in `/var/log/syslog`.

What can I check for or change? I am used to getting full transcript whenever I add `-v`, but I get nothing on the terminal.

We are migrating to OmniOSce, running sendmail 8.14.4.

Comment: Are you SURE you are executing sendmail by sendmail.org?  You may check SMTP greeting message produced by `echo quit | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs`

Comment: Ah, that seems to be the issue. returns `sendmail: no recipients`. Should return `220 fqdn.example.com ESMTP Sendmail ...` `221 2.0.0`...`closing connection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this by installing and configuring `sendmail` from **pkgsrc** package repository.